# Oracle Jet 11 - DetailedRouteConfig canEnter equivalent (Ojet 3.2)

Tags: path, router, oracle-jet

In Oracle Jet 3.2 I used to be able to specify is a user use a route or not:

```
                    self.routingInfo = ko.observable({
                    'signin': {label: 'Sign In', canEnter: true, isDefault: true},
                    'home': {label: 'Home', canEnter: true},
                    'adminPage': {label: 'Admin', canEnter: self.isAdmin},                    
                });
```

In Oracle Jet 11 the routes and core router syntax seems slightly different and it doesn't seem like I can use canEnter in the route details (the code comes from the navdrawer default template)

```
  let navData = [
    { path: '', redirect: 'dashboard' },
    { path: 'dashboard', detail: { label: 'Dashboard', iconClass: 'oj-ux-ico-bar-chart' } },
    { path: 'incidents', detail: { label: 'Incidents', iconClass: 'oj-ux-ico-fire' } },
    { path: 'customers', detail: { label: 'Customers', iconClass: 'oj-ux-ico-contact-group'} },
    { path: 'about', detail: { label: 'About', iconClass: 'oj-ux-ico-information-s' } }
  ];
```

The oracleJet doc here: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/CoreRouter.html#CreateOptions

[image]

doesn't give me the "detail" params I can use (ex: label, iconClass,..).

How can I mimic the behavior of canEnter in OracleJet 11 CoreRouter?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implemented navigation in UI, too, but below solutions can at least give you a starting point if it isn't exactly what you have in your app.

If you're using an `<oj-navigation-list>` for navigation (with `current-item="[[router.stateId]]" selection="{{router.stateId}}"`), you can use `ojBeforeSelect` event to check if user has permissions to access that page.

Another idea is to have a property `roles` on each route in `navData` and filter it when building your data provider for the `<oj-navigation-list>` with the user's permissions.